# From probability distribution in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to probability distribution in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I am working on a research paper where I need to investigate conditions for the existence of probability distributions satisfying certain characteristics. I have already asked a related question ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401905/conditions-for-existence-of-a-distribution-with-full-support)), whose answers allowed me to frame better in my mind the problems I'm facing. In what follows, I report a close, although different, question. I will highlight the key differences below.

Consider a $6\times 1$ random vector
$$
\eta\equiv (\eta_1,\eta_2,..., \eta_6)
$$
satisfying the following property (hereafter, called Property 1):

**Property 1:** $$
 \begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1\\
\eta_2\\
\eta_3
\end{pmatrix}  \sim  \begin{pmatrix}
\eta_4\\
-\eta_2\\
\eta_5
\end{pmatrix}   \sim  \begin{pmatrix}
\eta_6\\
-\eta_3\\
-\eta_5
\end{pmatrix}  \sim  \begin{pmatrix}
-\eta_1\\
-\eta_4\\
-\eta_6
\end{pmatrix}  \sim G
$$
where "$\sim$" denotes "distributed as" and $G$ is an absolutely continuous distribution with full support on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

**Question A:** Let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the family of absolutely continuous distribution with full support on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and whose marginals are *symmetric around zero and identical*. For each $G\in \mathcal{G}$, does there exists a vector $\eta$ satisfying Property 1?

---

**Question B:** Let $\epsilon$ be a $4\times 1$ random vector
$$
\epsilon\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_1\\
\epsilon_2\\
\epsilon_3\\
\epsilon_0\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

For each $(G,\eta)$ satisfying Property 1, does there exist $\epsilon$ satisfying Property 2 described below?

**Property 2:**
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}*\epsilon=\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1\\
\eta_2\\
\eta_3\\
\eta_4\\
\eta_5\\
\eta_6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the distribution $F$ of $\epsilon$ is  absolutely continuous  with full support on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

---

**My thoughts:**

I believe that the answer to Question A is "Yes": any  distribution in $\mathcal{G}$ satisfies Property 1. Certainly, there exist distributions outside $\mathcal{G}$ that can also  satisfy Property 1.

I believe that the answer to Question B is "Yes" as well. However, I'm not 100% sure and I would appreciate your help. The answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401905/conditions-for-existence-of-a-distribution-with-full-support) suggest that: if $F$ is  absolutely continuous  with full support on $\mathbb{R}^4$, then $G$ is  absolutely continuous  with full support on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Here, however, I'm asking something different: if $G$ is  absolutely continuous  with full support on $\mathbb{R}^3$, can we always find a distribution $F$ for $\epsilon$ that is absolutely continuous  with full support on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to both questions is negative.

**Question A.**
You ask whether for all $G\in\mathcal{G}$, there exist a random vector $\eta=(\eta_i)_{1\le i\le 6}$ such that they satisfy Condition 1 together.

If $G$ were not assumed to be fully supported, the answer would be easily seen to be negative: taking $G$ supported on $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x=y\}$ would force $\eta_1=\eta_2$, $\eta_4=-\eta_2$ and $-\eta_1=-\eta_4$ almost everywhere, which are incompatible.

But you can start from there and change $G$ slightly to be fully supported: simply start with any distribution supported on $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x=y\}$ with equal and centrally symmetric marginals; assume further that the marginals give a mass less than $1/5$ to $[-1,1]$ (**added in edit:** previously was $1/4$, but we need some room because of the perturbation). Define $G$ as a convolution of that distribution with a Gaussian $\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\varepsilon)$ for some small positive $\varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon$ small enough, you can ensure $G(\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid \lvert x-y\rvert>1/4\})<1/4$ and that any marginal of $G$ give a mass less than $1/5$ to $[-1,1]$. If a random vector $\eta$ were to satisfy condition 1 with $G$, you would have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\lvert \eta_4\rvert\le 1) &<1/4 \\
\mathbb{P}(\lvert \eta_1-\eta_2\rvert>1/4) &<1/4 \\
\mathbb{P}(\lvert \eta_4+\eta_2\rvert>1/4) &<1/4 \\
\mathbb{P}(\lvert \eta_1-\eta_4\rvert>1/4) &<1/4 \\
\end{align*}

With positive probability, we would thus have $\lvert \eta_1-\eta_2\rvert\le 1/4$, $\lvert \eta_4+\eta_2\rvert\le 1/4$, $\lvert \eta_1-\eta_4\rvert \le1/4$ and $\lvert \eta_4\rvert > 1$. Now, this is impossible since
$$\lvert \eta_4+\eta_4\rvert \le \lvert \eta_4-\eta_1\rvert + \lvert\eta_1-\eta_2\rvert+\lvert\eta_2+\eta_4\rvert. $$
(I took more room than needed, but that does the trick.)

**Question B. (added in edit)**

Simply take $\eta$ a normal vector $\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_6)$. Then condition 1 holds with $G$ a normal distribution, but for any $\epsilon$ its image under the matrix is contained in its image vector space, which has dimension $4$ at most since it is a $6\times 4$ matrix. This cannot have a fully supported law, hence cannot equal $\eta$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm not understanding the conclusion "[...] this is impossible since [...]". Is there any "tractable" way to restrict $\mathcal{G}$ to $\mathcal{G}_{\text{restricted}}$ such that property 1 holds for each $G\in \mathcal{G}_{\text{restricted}}$? How about question B)?

Comment: I think this is a clear counterexample. Perhaps another way to argue is that the restriction of full support is quite useless, since Property 1 remains when taking limits in distribution (i.e., if  $\eta^\varepsilon$ satisfy Property 1 and $\eta^\varepsilon$ converges weakly to $\eta$, then also $\eta$ satisfies Property 1; where we simply define $G$ as the distribution of $(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3)$ and same for $G^\varepsilon$).

Comment: @TEX: the last, implicit step is that with positive probability $2<2\lvert\eta_4\rvert\le 3/4$. Question B is not formulated precisely enough for me to answer. Maybe you ask whether for all $G,\eta$ such that condition 1 holds, there is an $\epsilon$ such that the second in-line equation holds, but you should rephrase things more precisely.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Thank you. I have rephrased also Question B following your suggestion. Does it sound better?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner may I ask you another clarification on your answer: "If a random vector $\eta$ were to satisfy condition 1 with $G$, you would have [...]". Shouldn't the last probability statement be "$\mathbb{P}(|\eta_4-\eta_1|>\frac{1}{4})<\frac{1}{4}$"? How do you get the first probability statement "$\mathbb{P}(|\eta_4|\leq 1)<\frac{1}{4}$"?

Comment: @TEX given the absolute values, I don't see the difference between the last statement and your proposal. The first statement comes from the assumption on the initial marginals (in fact you get something slightly larger than $1/4$ because of the perturbation I will correct).

Comment: Thanks for the addendum on Question B. I try to rephrase what you have shown, just to make sure I understand. Let $\eta\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_6)$. Hence, $G\equiv \mathcal{N}(0,I_3)$ and Property 1 holds. Are you saying that: $\nexists$ a vector $\epsilon\equiv (\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_0)$ whose distribution $F$ has full support on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and such that $$\begin{cases}\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0=\eta_1\\ \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2=\eta_2\\ \epsilon_1-\epsilon_3=\eta_3\\ \epsilon_2-\epsilon_0=\eta_4 \\ \epsilon_2-\epsilon_3=\eta_5 \\ \epsilon_3-\epsilon_0=\eta_6\end{cases}$$?

Comment: @TEX yes, there can be no such vector. The image of the matrix is a dimension-4 subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$, so that applying the matrix to any random vector $\epsilon$ gives a random vector supported on that dimension-$4$ subspace, and cannot have full support (in particular cannot be $\eta$).

Comment: Isn't this in contrast with the answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401905/conditions-for-existence-of-a-distribution-with-full-support ? The answer says that if F has full support on $\mathbb{R}^4$ than G has full support on  $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that I am not looking for the full support of the whole vector $\eta$, but only of some of its subvectors.

Comment: @TEX there is no contradiction, your present question asks whether *for all* $G$ there exist an $\eta$ such that $(G,\eta)$ satisfy (2), while the property you refer to is that for all $(G,\eta)$ satisfying (2) with $\eta$ of full support, then $G$ must have full support. It feels like you are thinking about a different question than what you wrote, in which case you need to be more precise in your phrasing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have accepted your answer.